# Printing all occurrences of mapped data from 2 data frames in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, set

I have a dataframe: df1

```
  SAP_Name  SAP_Class  SAP_Sec
  Avi       5          Avi
  Rison     6          A 
  Slesh     7          B 
  San       8          C 
  Sud       7          B
```

df2:

```
Name_Fi Class std
Avi     5     fgh
Rison   6     Rij
Slesh   7     jkh
```

I am trying to get the mapping of headers basis the values contained in the columns of the 2 dataframes.

When used the below code:

```
dfs1 = {col1: df1[col1].drop_duplicates() for col1 in df1.columns}
set2 = {col2: set(df2[col2]) for col2 in df2.columns}
d = {}
for col2, v2 in set2.items():
    for col1, v1 in dfs1.items():
        cond = set(v2).issubset(v1)
        if cond:
           d[col2] = col1
print(d)
```

I have a result:

```
{'Name_Fi': 'SAP_Name', 'Class': 'SAP_Class'}
```

Desired output:

```
{'Name_Fi': ['SAP_Name','SAP_Sec'], 'Class': 'SAP_Class'}
```

Basically trying to print every matching column header wherever there are matching values in df1. Can anypne pleae help?

Comment: But why should `SAP_Sec` be included? There's no column in `df2` whose values are a *subset* of columns values in `df1['SAP_Sec']`.

Comment: @jpp sorry for the late reply. But if you see the first row of sap sec, it's a subset as it's contains one of the names. Don't know how I missed this comment. But appreciate your solutions. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need `intersection` between `set`s, so for performance was in `dict comprehension` converted both values of dictionary to `set`s:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dfs1 = {col1: set(df1[col1].drop_duplicates()) for col1 in df1.columns}
set2 = {col2: set(df2[col2]) for col2 in df2.columns}

d = defaultdict(list)
for col2, v2 in set2.items():
    for col1, v1 in dfs1.items():
        cond = v2.intersection(v1)
        if cond:
           d[col2].append(col1)
print(d)
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'Name_Fi': ['SAP_Name', 'SAP_Sec'], 'Class': ['SAP_Class']})
```

Comment: Great..!! I have never worked with intersections. Thanks for the quick help @jezrael

Answer (score 1):

You aren't looking for `issubset` here, since this will only work if values in one column are a subset of the values in another, e.g. *all* the values of `df2['Name_Fi']` are contained in `df1['SAP_Sec']`.. Instead, you can use `set.intersection`, or the syntactic sugar `&` to check if there is any overlap.

You can combine this idea with `collections.defaultdict` extract your desired result:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for col2, v2 in set2.items():
    for col1, v1 in dfs1.items():
        cond = set(v2) & set(v1)
        if cond:
            d[col2].append(col1)

print(d)

defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'Name_Fi': ['SAP_Name', 'SAP_Sec'],
                             'Class': ['SAP_Class']})
```

More efficiently, you can calculate `set` objects in your comprehensions to avoid explicit conversion in your nested loop:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dfs1 = {col1: set(df1[col1]) for col1 in df1}
set2 = {col2: set(df2[col2]) for col2 in df2}

d = defaultdict(list)

for col2, v2 in set2.items():
    for col1, v1 in dfs1.items():
        if v2 & v1:
            d[col2].append(col1)

print(d)
```

For larger arrays, you may find using `pd.Series.unique` + `any` with a generator expression more efficient:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
A = pd.Series(np.random.randint(0, 1000, 10000)).unique()
B = pd.Series(np.random.randint(0, 100000, 10000)).unique()

%timeit np.in1d(B, A).any()     # 1.1 ms per loop
%timeit set(A) & set(B)         # 1.46 ms per loop
%timeit any(i in B for i in A)  # 102 µs per loop
```

Comment: Thanks @jpp,however the code runs for long when used against large files. My actual file has 112444 rows × 446 columns and the target file to be changed has 3 rows × 35 columns. But thanks a lot for the help, would be referring this for future references. :)

Comment: @anky_91, For performance you can try `any` [see the benchmarking at the bottom of my answer].